# Can't post value back to action Method using @Html.BeginForm

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I have some code, where when the user clicks on the "x" icon then call the CancelPendingQuote action method passing along the requestId in the requestUrl. The action method is hitting but the value is not included in the requestIdEncrypted parameter, thus the action method parameter has a null value.

Pending List

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("CancelPendingQuote", "Quote", new { requestIdEncrypted = request.RequestIdEncrypted }, FormMethod.Get, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "removeRequest" }))
{
  <span data-bind="click: function(data, event){  userWarning_Dialog('#removeRequest_dialog', event); }">

  <img src="~/Areas/Waybill/Content/Images/Normal_Size/posta_delete_20px.png" />
  <img src="~/Areas/Waybill/Content/Images/Normal_Size/posta_delete_mouseover_20px.png" style="display:none" />

 </span>
}
```

Knockout userWarning function that submits the form. This is called when image "x" is clicked.

```
removeRequest: function (model, event)
    {
        var form = $("#removeRequest").closest("form");

        $(form).submit().error(function (messageObj) {
            // if fail return error message
            $(".information-bar").trigger("ErrorText", messageObj.message);               
        });
        $("#removeRequest_dialog").dialog("close");

    },
```

Action method

```
    [Authorize]
      public ActionResult CancelPendingQuote(string requestIdEncrypted)
    {
        int requestId = Convert.ToInt16(Decryption.Decrypt(requestIdEncrypted));

        _controllerContent.QuoteService.Value.CancelPendingQuoteRequest(requestId);
        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
    }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: why your form method is Get? it Must be FormMethod.Post. your action is changing the model!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things here.  For one, you need to make sure that the names of the object being posted to the server match up with the Controller's parameter. For instance, if you send this Javascript object up:

```
{ requestIdEncrypted: "exampleString" }
```

or

```
{ requestIdEncrypted: viewModel.requestId() }
```

then your Controller method should accept the input.

Secondly, from your code it's not evident to me how the data is being posted.  `$(form).submit().error(function (messageObj)` is a little confusing: is this line responsible for submitting the form?  Is it a function that would be called if the form submission is unsuccessful?  Is it working?  It's [not clear to me what you're trying to do with this](http://api.jquery.com/error/). You may have to figure out another way to attach an error handler to the form, if this is what you're trying to do - unless it's working alright.